# What functionality would I lose if I disable browser-based Java?

Tags: security, browser, java

I am reading that disabling Java—not JavaScript—will make my computer safer form malicious software attacks.  All indications are that it will indeed make it safer, but there are no real reasons out there as what I will lose in the browsing experience, if anything. Can someone tell me what I would or would not experience and is Java really necessary these day for browsing?

Comment: Of course it's not a proven fact that disabling any extensions or plugins *will* make your browsing any safer but, it's true that the less plugins your browser has, the less it's prone to be unstable or unsafe. I always recommend to disable anything you don't actively use, and look for alternatives that don't rely completely on them, or at least use free alternatives (lightspark, openjdk) and if you're on linux always use the repos ;).

Comment: I never ever use Java anymore.

Answer (score 37):

> Can someone tell me what I would or would not experience and and is
>   Java really necessary these day for browsing?

This is a fairly good question. What it boils down to is this: If you need Java in a browser, you will know so right away. If you don’t need Java—and are even unaware if you are even using it—chances are good you will never miss it and never bump into it again; the risk of a casual user tripping over a site that would truly need Java to function in 2015 is rare at best nowadays.

Just so you understand the history of Java and the web, Java is essentially a “black box” virtual machine that allows you to code in Java and then run that code on any system that can run Java. The concept was that Java would be a middle ground platform that could run on any machine; Windows, Macintosh, Linux, etc… So the Java plug-in simply allows you to run Java apps from within a web browser. This was appealing in the early days of the Internet due to lack of cross-platform compatibilities and other “rough edges” of the early Internet.

But in 2015, most of the “fancy” base-level functionality that Java provided in the past—cool graphics and effects and such—are now handled within the browser itself via CSS, HTML and JavaScript. Back in the late-1990s/early-2000s lots of creative sites used Java because native browsers could not handle the tricks one could only do in Java back then. Heck, Java even came bundled as a basic plugin in Netscape Navigator back in the day thanks to the commonly accepted functionality it provided.

Now where you might miss it in 2015 depends on what kinds of sites you access. For example, I know that many financial systems accessible online—such as personal tax systems, payroll gateways and other such systems—use complex Java applications to allow end users to get a richer experience with their financial tools. So if you are using your machine to access web-based financial applications like that, then you definitely need Java enabled. But in my experience, even in those cases, many such institutions are slowly moving their archaic Java-based systems to a more stable, non-Java based setup that takes better advantage of modern web browser functionality.

For example, a little over a year ago anyone using the browser-based screen sharing software/service [GoToMeeting](http://gotomeeting.com) needed to have Java enabled in their browser and as well as on their system. But [as explained in this support forum thread on their site](https://community.gotomeeting.com/gotomeeting/topics/does_a_person_need_to_have_java_enabled_to_attend_a_meeting) they have now officially dropped the Java requirement in favor of their own non-Java-based software tool:

> In the past we used to use Java to automate launching our software, we
>   have since replaced that method with our own launcher. Since
>   introducing our launcher we no longer use Java.

So my advice is if Java worries you as a potential security concern on a browser level, just disable it for now. I’m pretty confident you will not miss it. And if—in like 8 to 9 months—you need Java for some reason, deal with it then.

Comment: "...allows you to code in Java and then run that code on any system..." mind, that's not really something Java can do much better than other languages. The difference is that Java allows you to _compile_ the code and then run that compiled _bytecode_ on any system, whereas in other languages you need to supply the _source code_ and compile/interpret it right on the target platform. It can be argued that this is [the right way](http://www.fsf.org/about/what-is-free-software) to do it anyway, in particular WRT security if you don't altogether trust the site.

Comment: Jake, please keep your edits substantial. The last 5 revisions were rather superficial and these edits always push the post to the front page, leaving less room for other posts. Thanks.

Comment: I work for a big bank in Germany and their remote software to work from home requires Java among other things.

Comment: I agree. I did not install Java to my new PC in december 2012. I'm full-time software developer and avid internet user and since that date there was one case when I needed Java at desktop (some tool) and **zero** cases where I needed it at some web site. So I'm keeping it away from my PC with ease, missing nothing. I also support the claim that corporate applications still massively rely on it in their browser apps.

Answer (score 4):

You will encounter Java on the web mostly in form of Java applets. These are applications which appear as box-shaped areas embedded in webpages. How your browser handles these when you don't have Java enabled depends on the browser, but most show it in form of a gray rectangle which prompts you in some way to install Java.

So when you encounter a website which requires Java for an applet, you will know.

You won't see many Java applets anyway. While they were a common sight during the web boom in the late 90s / early 2000s, they become quite rare nowadays, because the technology got displaced by Adobe Flash which now itself gets displaced by HTML5.

Comment: The description in the final paragraph is not really accurate. Java applets, flash, and html 5 are all different tools that are useful for different purposes. There is some overlap, but it's not a matter of one replacing another. And it's not really true that java applets were common in the early days of the web. They were always uncommon. They basically never caught on.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends, some websites need Java to work, others dont. For example if you want to update your graphic card driver through [Nvidia](http://www.nvidia.com/Download/Scan.aspx?lang=en-us) website it would need Java for that. There are lots of other websites that uses Java applets, for chess, gameing, weather, watching movies with subtitles. So if you visit those sites, and they run on Java you need to have Java too.

In general it could represent a security threat, but also a security threat is running an Windows XP. So if your Java is up to date, and your OS, and you dont wisit some very “strange” website you can feel secure, or in other words Java will not one to blame if something “bad” happends.

Oracle—the owner of Java—is updating quite frequently, to make it more secure. But it can represent a security flaw if you don’t update your Java regularly. You can read more on [Oracle’s](https://www.java.com/en/download/faq/whatis_java.xml) web site to get a biger picture, and start with this [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_applet).

Comment: *"Java will not one to blame if something “bad” happends"* - This is totally wrong.  If your machine gets compromised due to a zero-day vulnerability in Java, *of course* Java will be the one to blame.  There have been a number of such vulnerabilities in the past.  That's why [many security experts](http://krebsonsecurity.com/2013/01/what-you-need-to-know-about-the-java-exploit/) recommend [disabling Java](https://krebsonsecurity.com/how-to-unplug-java-from-the-browser/): it removes one attack vector.

Answer (score 0):

When I was in college, many of the (required) educational apps required Java e.g. Blackboard, the college library's website, wolfram alpha, webassign, etc. Disabling Java in my browser broke the functionality of the apps. Consequently, keep Java up-to-date and use the highest security settings possible that your apps allow.