# Why is Java running on my PC when I never use it?

Tags: windows, java

Java runs constantly. Is it needed? I did not install it. No one else uses my laptop; a Dell Inspiron N5010. I don’t do any Java programming. Don’t know how it got there; I believe that are versions 7 & 8 are installed. Only use the laptop for Internet Explorer, Excel, Word, AOL, Ask, Map Quest, online banking and a few games. I’m just an old disabled non-technical fart.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to stop jucheck from running? Java won't remember "Check for Updates Automatically" setting](http://superuser.com/questions/130961/how-to-stop-jucheck-from-running-java-wont-remember-check-for-updates-automat)

Comment: Many games use Java, and some bank software does too. Really impossible to guess where it came from. Some online PC diagnostics do too (Like NVidia's online video card detection)

Comment: To make your system more secure make sure that Java in your web browser(s) is disabled (along with Flash). That secures you from 95% of the drive-by garbage out there. Java simply being on your system otherwise isn't necessarily a risk.

Answer (score 2):

> Why is Java running on my PC when I never use it?

I go into detail in [this answer on what Java might be used for nowadays](https://superuser.com/a/880901/167207). In general, if an application is not actively using Java, it won’t be running. Yes, the program and control panels might be “active” and installed, but Java itself should not be running and should not be a concern.

That said, you state this:

> Only use the laptop for Internet Explorer, Excel, Word, AOL, Ask, Map Quest, online
>   banking and a few games.

The reality is any one of those programs—especially a web browser like Internet Explorer—might have a Java plugin installed to allow Java applications to run in the web browser. The most common use for Java as a web plug-in application in 2015 would be for something like an enhanced banking application or maybe online games. Many banking sites are completely browser-based nowadays and do not need Java to allow you to use them. But there might be a few banking/financial sites out there that still need a Java application running via a browser plugin to allow you to use their site.

In general, if you believe it is “running” because you see control panel items for Java, I would not worry at all. The control panel’s existence on the system in and of itself does not mean/imply a Java application is actually active on your machine. It’s just a control panel; nothing more and nothing less.

Answer (score 0):

There are various application programs on the system which runs on Java or use Java Virtual Machine to run themselves and some use the services of Java that's why it is constantly running on your system. Keep Java on your system as it is useful for other programs.